# Iterating through array and not all items are showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

See the example here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/b2y1tagk/

With the following code I would think that I would get all three elements appended to result, but I don't. I get:

`primary - bar
secondary - glorp`

```
var elements = [{
        type: 'secondary',
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        type: 'primary',
        name: "bar"
    }, {
        type: 'secondary',
        name: "glorp"
    }];

    var elementItem;
    $(elements).each(function () {
        if (this.type == 'primary') {
            elementItem = this.type + ' - ' + this.name + '<br />';
        } else {
            elementItem += this.type + ' - ' + this.name + '<br />';
        }
    });
$('#results').append(elementItem);
```

So I'm thinking that I should add the `+=` operator to the first portion of the if condition, but when I do I get this:

`undefinedsecondary - foo
primary - bar
secondary - glorp`

It doesn't matter what order these are in when they are generated, they just all have to be there when complete. I feel sure that I am missing something obvious, can someone tell me what that is?

Comment: You probably want `$.each` not `$.fn.each`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting your `elementItem` variable with `=` when you reach the primary type. Try appending every item in your list. Initialize the elementItem by `var elementItem=''`.

```
    var elements = [{
        type: 'secondary',
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        type: 'primary',
        name: "bar"
    }, {
        type: 'secondary',
        name: "glorp"
    }];

    var elementItem = '';
    $(elements).each(function () {
        if (this.type == 'primary') {
            elementItem += this.type + ' - ' + this.name + '<br />';
        } else {
            elementItem += this.type + ' - ' + this.name + '<br />';
        }
    });
$('#results').append(elementItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
elementItem = this.type + ' - ' + this.name + '<br />';
```

needs to be:

```
elementItem = this.type + ' - ' + this.name + '<br />' + elementItem;
```

Otherwise, you overwrite it if primary is not the first item.

Initialize it with `var elementItem = "";` so it doesn't typecast elementItem to the string "undefined"

http://jsfiddle.net/b2y1tagk/3/